# How far have we got to go?

Tags: discussion

So, we're at 90 days, and we're obviously not there yet - but out of curiosity from those more experienced in these things than I, how much longer do you estimate we need to stay in beta? Or is it really impossible to tell?

I'm just curious :-)

Answer (score 6):

90 days is just about the time this question gets asked on many sites. That's why I've written a few blog posts on the topic. They are generally applicable here:

[**When will my site graduate?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

Answer (score 4):

At the very least we need a lot more traffic before they take us out of beta. We'll also need to improve our [site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659/the-great-outdoors), especially questions/day and visits/day. And despite the "at least 90 days," it's much more common nowadays to stay in beta closer to a year. But don't worry about the time for now, just get the word out and bring traffic in, and we'll graduate eventually.

Answer (score 4):

My interpretation of a few events leads me to conclude the following

- Promotion of good questions gets results.  We've discussed which ones were good in another post.  I've seen spikes in new visits after time when I know we're promoted those.
- Good Q/A brings traffic.   Our questions and answers per day has to increase, but with quality content.  When people see no or little new content they check the site less.  When they feel that if they wait, they'll miss something then they will check more.

So  --  Ask good questions and advertise them in your social media outlets.